# Sum type in variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I have a template function defined for variadic templates of two kinds:

```
template<typename ...A>
void foo(std::shared_future<A>... args) {
    // ...
}

template<typename ...A>
void foo(std::future<A>&... args) {
    // ...
}
```

This works for `foo(a, b, c)` if `a`, `b` and `c` are either all futures, or all shared futures. How can I adapt this code to work for any **mix of both types templates**, i.e. both shared and raw futures in this case?

Comment: Is it deliberate that `shared_future` is taken by value, and `future` by reference?

Comment: It is, yes, I need `shared_future` to get copied, while `future` is moved. But that's just details of the example case anyways. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first accept arbitrary types `Futures...` and then use SFINAE to restrict them to `std::[shared_]future`:

```
template<class>
struct is_future_or_shared_future : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct is_future_or_shared_future<std::future<T>> : std::true_type {};

template<class T>
struct is_future_or_shared_future<std::shared_future<T>> : std::true_type {};

template<class... Futures, typename = std::enable_if_t<
    std::conjunction_v<is_future_or_shared_future<Futures>...>>>
void foo(Futures&... args) {
    // ...
}
```

If you want to take both lvalues and rvalues, use forwarding references:

```
template<class T>
using remove_cvref_t = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;

template<class... Futures, typename = std::enable_if_t<         
    std::conjunction_v<is_future_or_shared_future<remove_cvref_t<Futures>>...>>>
void foo(Futures&&... args) {
    // ...
}
```

To access the inner type you can use a traits class:

```
template<class>
struct inner_type;

template<class T>
struct inner_type<std::future<T>> { 
    using type = T;
};

template<class T>
struct inner_type<std::shared_future<T>> {
    using type = T;
};
```

and then write:

```
typename B = std::result_of_t<
    F(typename inner_type<remove_cvref_t<Futures>>::type...)>;
```

Comment: It's a good start, thanks! Now actually I also need to access the inner type `A` (or `T`) in your example, cause my real case is a bit more complicated and has some `typename B = typename std::result_of<F(A...)>::type` in it.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to allow future<T>& but not future<T> while keeping shared_future<T>? `remove_cvref_t` makes things too permissive I fear. (Alright maybe I should share my whole file)

Comment: Why doesn't using `is_future_or_shared_future<std::future<T>&> : std::true_type` work?

Comment: @Lithy, `is_future_or_shared_future<std::future<T>&>` should work if you don't remove a reference with `std::remove_reference_t<T>`. After applying `std::remove_reference`, `std::future<T>&` becomes `std::future<T>`.

Comment: @Lithy, `is_future_or_shared_future<T>` should match a type exactly, with `const` and `&` qualifiers if any.

Comment: For some reason it did not work, likely because of other stuff around. I figured it out, here is now the full code, working ;) https://github.com/eliemichel/LilyFuture

Comment: @Lithy, it might not work because `T` in `is_future_or_shared_future` can be `const` and/or `&` qualified, and (almost) all combinations should be specialized for.